# How to dynamically order many-to-many relationship with JPA or HQL?

Tags: java, jpa, many-to-many, hql, sql-order-by

I have a mapping like this:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinTable(
            name="product_product_catalog",
            joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="product_catalog", referencedColumnName="product_catalog")},
            inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="product", referencedColumnName="product")})
    public List<Product> products = new ArrayList<Product>();
```

I can fetch the products for the catalog nicely, but I can't (dynamically) order the products.
How could I order them?
I probably have to write a many-to-many HQL query with the order-by clause? I though of passing the orderBy field name string to the query, or is there a better solution?

Tables are:
products,
product_catalog,
product_product_catalog (associative table)

P.S. Using Play! Framework JPASupport for my entities.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

> I can fetch the products for the catalog nicely, but I can't (dynamically) order the products. How could I order them?

Not possible if you let JPA retrieve the association. Mappings are static, the best thing you can do with mappings is to specify the order at "retrieve time":

> #### 9.1.28 OrderBy Annotation
>
> The `OrderBy` annotation specifies the ordering of the elements of a collection valued association at the point when the association is retrieved.
>
> ```
> @Target({METHOD, FIELD}) @Retention(RUNTIME)
> public @interface OrderBy {
>    String value() default "";
> }
> ```
>
> The syntax of the value ordering
>   element is an **orderby_list**, as
>   follows:
>
> ```
> orderby_list::= orderby_item [,orderby_item]*
> orderby_item::= property_or_field_name [ASC | DESC]
> ```
>
> If ASC or DESC is not specified, ASC (ascending order) is assumed.
>
> If the ordering element is not specified, ordering by the primary key of the associated entity is assumed.
>
> The property or field name must correspond to that of a persistent property or field of the associated class. The properties or fields used in the ordering must correspond to columns for which comparison operators are supported.
>
> **Example:**
>
> ```
> @Entity public class Course {
>   ...
>   @ManyToMany
>   @OrderBy("lastname ASC")
>   public List<Student> getStudents() {...};
>   ...
> }
> ```

So either use a custom finder or sort your list from Java using a `Comparator`.