# JPA @ManyToMany relation, @JoinTable and @JoinColumn @OrderBy

Tags: hibernate, jpa, sql-order-by, join, joincolumn

## TABLE_A

- ID
- SORT

## TABLE_B

- ID

There is a REF Table by using these tables ManyToMany associated

## TABLE_REF

- A_ID
- B_ID

I am gettind datas by using B.getAs()

I want to get As OrderBy TABLE_A.SORT field. For this, I try to add OrderBy, however it cannot access ORDER field in relation of B neighter A.

Thats why, I think if I can Join SORT field to REF table, too, I can use @OrderBy(clause="ORDER") parameter in relation map of B.

But for hours I couldnot find any solutions.

Here is codes I use for mapping:

TABLE_A:

```
@ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, targetEntity = Role.class, cascade={CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST})
@Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
@JoinTable(name = "NC_ADMIN_ROLE_PAGE_XREF", joinColumns =
        @JoinColumn(name = "PAGE_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID"), 
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ROLE_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID", nullable = true))
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE, region="ncAdminElements")
@BatchSize(size = 50)
private List<Role> allRoles = new ArrayList<Role>(10);
```

TABLE_B:

```
@Column(name = "NAME")
private String name;
@ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, targetEntity = Page.class, cascade={CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST})
@Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
@JoinTable(name = "NC_ADMIN_ROLE_PAGE_XREF", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ROLE_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID"), 
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "PAGE_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID", nullable = true))
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE, region="ncAdminElements")
@BatchSize(size = 50)
private List<Page> allPages = new ArrayList<Page>(10);
```

What I exactly want, TABLE_B.getAllPages() ordered by TABLE_A.DISPLAY_ORDER

Any well-done source about MAPPING RELATIONS in hibernate for dummies is appropriate for me.

Comment: I'am afraid you won't be able to do this.

See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002135/how-to-dynamically-order-many-to-many-relationship-with-jpa-or-hql

Comment: @kirlisakal do you have find a solution?

Comment: sorry, its been a long time, and even I dont remember since I dont work in that project any longer.